# Page not found error message on Stack Overflow when I login to my account

Tags: support, accounts

Man, I'm [SuperUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367918/super-user), my account on SO was:

[image: SuperUser]

but today a strange thing happened when I logged into my account, I saw :

[image: SuperUser]

My account is not reachable and has totally changed. What is wrong with it?
Please can anyone help me in recovering my account?

Comment: Are you still experiencing difficulties with this?

Comment: @AnnaLear Now I have compromised with that account and I'm using that one as mine, but still I'm worried about how that could happen to my account :-(

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely contact the admins as stated in the 404 page, especially since it is an account-related question:

> If you feel something is missing that should be here, [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

---

Upon further investigation, your meta account seem to be linked to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056042/arshay.

The account you are referring to might have been merged into yours.

Comment: OK but my account URL was http://stackoverflow.com/users/1367918/super-user and how can that be merged

Comment: Merging of accounts will usually take place when there is abuse between the two accounts (eg. cross-voting). Did you do anything like that? Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170072/is-stack-overflow-merging-two-different-accounts-by-email-without-the-users-con